# phpfox : how to get my group name?

Tags: phpfox

How can I get the group name I do belong ?

I could get these infos:

`$user = Phpfox::getService('user')->get($username, false)`;

> [user_group_id] => 6 [title] =>
>   user_group_title_3749ea904585437bb7e01c7e1571e162

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
 SELECT ug.title FROM phpfox_user as u 
join phpfox_user_group as ug on ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id 
WHERE u.user_id=1
```

Then put the result in _p function

Example:

```
$sUserTitle = Phpfox::getLib('database')->select('ug.title')
->from(':user', 'u')
->join(':user_group', 'ug', 'ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id')
->where('u.user_id=' . Phpfox::getUserId())
->execute('getSlaveField');
echo _p($sUserTitle)
```